# Flask: Static folder files getting routed to a app_url

Tags: python, flask, webserver, web-frameworks

```
@app.route('/<date>/<username>/<path:filename>')
@login_required
@nocache
def custom_static(filename, username, date):
    path = os.path.join(app.config['CUSTOM_STATIC_PATH'],"username", username, date)
    print "Path: {}".format(path)
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, filename)):
        return send_from_directory(path, filename)
    else:
        print "File does not exist: {}".format(filename)
        return
```

Error:

```
Path: ./DataWebserver/username/js/static
File does not exist: bootstrap-datepicker.min.js
    enter code here
```

The interesting part is that it works if my route has only 2 variables like

```
@app.route('/<date>/<username>/')
```

instead of

```
@app.route('/<date>/<username>/<path:filename>')
```

Answer (score 0):

I dug a little more deeper and realized that the original API route endpoint was ambiguous and also mapping the the css/js path.

```
@app.route('/<date>/<username>/<path:filename>')

// Static
/static/css/file.css
/static/js/file.js

// User Content
/2017-02-06/my_user_name/my_file
```

The fix on my end was to make my API route with a endpoint name that is not dynamic

```
@app.route('/file/<date>/<username>/<path:filename>')
```